# Import nameof function from the ts-nameof package that is not exported in d.ts

Tags: javascript, typescript

I found an interesting package and want to use it in my typescript application: https://github.com/dsherret/ts-nameof

But I cannot import `nameof` function. It is not exported in d.ts file:

```
declare module "ts-nameof" {
    interface Api {
        ...
    }
    var func: Api;
    export = func;
}

declare function nameof<T>(func?: (obj: T) => void): string;
declare function nameof(obj: Object | null | undefined): string;
declare namespace nameof {
    function full<T>(periodIndex?: number): string;
    function full(obj: Object | null | undefined, periodIndex?: number): string;
}
```

How should I import `nameof` function into my typescript module?

for `import 'ts-nameof';` I have `Uncaught ReferenceError: nameof is not defined` error.

Answer (score 3):

Add this into `tsd.d.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/ts-nameof/ts-nameof.d.ts" />
```

Make sure to put correct path to `node_modules`

Comment: Where do you put the `tsd.d.ts` file? And do I need to reference it from every ts file, or can I somehow reference it once for the whole project?